# Sort rows in MATLAB in a cell array that have non numeric values in sorting column

Tags: matlab, sorting

Suppose that we have this cell array:

```
X = {'Jack' 43 4
'John' 63 2
'James' 34 '---'
'Jones' 12 7
'Bill' 31 '---'
'Anthony' 53 3};
```

I want sort as `descending order` by `last column`. I want have `'---'` elements (in last column) in end of output like this :

```
X_new = {'Jones' 12 7
,'Jack' 43 4
,'Anthony' 53 3
,'John' 63 2
,'James' 31 '---'
,'Bill' 34 '---'}
```

**Question two** : In second case I want another formula that I can have this :

```
X_new2 = {'Jones' 12 7
,'Jack' 43 4
,'Anthony' 53 3
,'John' 63 2
,'Bill' 34 '---'
,'James' 31 '---'}
```

that two last columns sorted by column 2 (as `descending order`) . How can I do these?

That is a sample question for a much bigger matrix that contains values between 0 and 100 in last column so We need a general solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the code and the description.
Also, in the code for `X_new` it seems that `Bill` needs to have `31`, and `James`, `34`.

Comment: Following the discussion in the answers - this seems to be an answered question. Does neither solution work for you?

Comment: Yes. But I think Luis Mendo answer is more shorter so I was thinking maybe we can improve it to a more general solution. If not your answer is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).

Generally speaking, I'd replace the `'---'` strings with a number for the sorting process, and then change them back afterwards.

Case 1 and 2 are commented in the code.

```
SUFFICIENTLY_NEGATIVE_NUMBER = -999; %//making this -inf is not a good idea

X = {'Jack' 43 4
'John' 63 2
'James' 34 '---'
'Jones' 12 7
'Bill' 31 '---'
'Anthony' 53 3};

X_new = X;
X_new((strcmp(X_new(:,3),'---')),3)={SUFFICIENTLY_NEGATIVE_NUMBER};
X_new = sortrows(X_new,-3); %//Case 1
X_new2 = sortrows(X_new,[-3,2]); %// Case 2

X_new(cell2mat(X_new(:,3))==SUFFICIENTLY_NEGATIVE_NUMBER,3)={'---'};
X_new2(cell2mat(X_new2(:,3))==SUFFICIENTLY_NEGATIVE_NUMBER,3)={'---'};
```

The 2nd arguments of `sortrows` in my example determines the order of columns by which to sort, and their sign is the direction (ascending \ descending for (+) \ (-), respectively.)

Comment: in `X_new(strcmp(X_new,'---'))={SUFFICIENTLY_NEGATIVE_NUMBER};` I have other cells that may have '---' in first two columns. How can I solve this?

Comment: Then you should only look for `---` in the 3rd column. See edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**

Convert last column to strings (with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)); sort that; and use the index of the sorting (second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)) to build the result:

```
[~, ind] = sort(cellfun(@num2str, X(:,3), 'uniformoutput', 0));
X_new = X(ind(end:-1:1),:);
```

**Second question:**

Find rows of `X_new` that have `'---'` in the third column; sort accoording to the second column; and again use the index of the sorting to build the result. This assumes the second column contains only numbers, as in your example.

```
ind2 = find(cellfun(@(s) isequal(s,'---'), X_new(:,3)));
[~, ind3] = sort([X_new{ind2,2}]);
X_new2 = X_new;
X_new2(ind2,:) = X_new(ind2(ind3(end:-1:1)),:);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. In second question I want have same structure but order rows with '---' in third rows by second column in the end of previous cell array.

Comment: @user2991243 Ok, now I see what you want. I have updated my answer

Comment: check your question with this values : `X = {'Jack' 43 4 ; 'John' 63 2 ; 'James' 34 '---' ; 'Jones' 12 14 ; 'Bill' 31 '---' ; 'Anthony' 53 10};` There is problem with different values. We need a general solution.

Comment: @user2991243 - We cannot know more than you tell us. Based on the examples you provided, we make assumptions on the structure of the data. You should add to your question some "pathological" examples of inputs that the sorting algorithm must cope with.

Comment: Yes. That's true. That is a sample question for a much bigger matrix that contains values between 0 and 100 in last column. I added information in the question. thank you again.